# React MUI Autocomplete: Update state of InputField onChange or onClose

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I want to use a a MUI Autocomplete component but with another value in the inputfield as selected in the options after the selection.
For example: My option is an objet with first and surname and I want only the surname in the field (and the firstname in another one).

Using the prop onChange: Triggers only if the option was realy changed. If someone selects the the same option again, it will not trigger in some cases.

Using the prop onClose: Triggers every time when the list of options is closing and the reason can be used as a condition. That works fine. But when the same option is selected a second time, the text value of the option is set to the Inputfield, not the state change - what works great when the option is selected the first time.

Here is an example code with the two versions (onChange and onClose):

```
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import { TextField, Typography } from "@mui/material";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [optionData, setOptionData] = useState([
    { firstName: "Jane", surName: "Smith" },
    { firstName: "John", surName: "Doe" },
  ]);
  const [inputData, setInputData] = useState("");
  const [otherFieldData, setOtherFieldData] = useState("");

  const updateInputData = (newValue) => {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
      console.log("update Input fired with: ", newValue);
      setInputData(newValue.surName);
      setOtherFieldData(newValue.firstName);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Uses onChange (what is only fired when the option changes)</p>

      <Autocomplete
        id="name2"
        options={optionData}
        getOptionLabel={(option) =>
          option.surName === undefined
            ? option
            : `${option.firstName} ${option.surName}`
        }
        value={inputData}
        onChange={(e, value) => updateInputData(value)}
        freeSolo
        filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            required
            id="outlined-required"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setInputData(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={inputData}
            label="Name"
            key="Name"
          />
        )}
      />
      <p>Uses onClose (Fires always)</p>
      <Autocomplete
        id="name2"
        options={optionData}
        getOptionLabel={(option) =>
          option.surName === undefined
            ? option
            : `${option.firstName} ${option.surName}`
        }
        value={inputData}
        onClose={(e, reason) => {
          if (reason === "selectOption") {
            updateInputData(optionData[e.target.dataset.optionIndex]);
          }
        }}
        freeSolo
        filterOptions={(options, state) => options}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            required
            id="outlined-required"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setInputData(e.target.value);
            }}
            value={inputData}
            label="Name"
            key="Name"
          />
        )}
      />
      <p>The other field</p>
      <TextField
        value={otherFieldData}
        onChange={(e) => setOtherFieldData(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the code in the sandbox to try it: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/autocomplete-problem-njgxcs?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-93%2C1

When you choose the same option twice, you can see in the console the triggered function to set the state associated with the value of the inputfield - bit the textvalue of the option appears instead.

I am thankful for some guidiance on this problem.

On the second one (with the onClose prop) I expect in the example the state is always set with updateInputData - but after the first selection, every other try calls the method again but the inputfield gets the textvalue of the option as set in the getOptionLabel prop.